# mingw32-make: *** No targets. Stop

Tags: c++, c, compilation, makefile

I'm trying to compile a C++ project manually ( I'm a newbie )

I have a MakeFile.am that contains:

```
ifneq ($(WANT_JANSSON),)
JANSSON_INCLUDES= -I$(top_srcdir)/compat/jansson
else
JANSSON_INCLUDES=
endif

EXTRA_DIST  = example-cfg.json nomacro.pl

SUBDIRS     = compat

INCLUDES    = $(PTHREAD_FLAGS) -fno-strict-aliasing $(JANSSON_INCLUDES)

bin_PROGRAMS    = minerd

dist_man_MANS   = minerd.1

minerd_SOURCES  = elist.h miner.h compat.h \
          cpu-miner.c util.c \
          sha2.c scrypt.c
ifneq ($(ARCH_x86),)
minerd_SOURCES += sha2-x86.S scrypt-x86.S
endif
ifneq ($(ARCH_x86_64),)
minerd_SOURCES += sha2-x64.S scrypt-x64.S
endif
ifneq ($(ARCH_ARM),)
minerd_SOURCES += sha2-arm.S scrypt-arm.S
endif
minerd_LDFLAGS  = $(PTHREAD_FLAGS)
minerd_LDADD    = @LIBCURL@ @JANSSON_LIBS@ @PTHREAD_LIBS@ @WS2_LIBS@
minerd_CPPFLAGS = @LIBCURL_CPPFLAGS@
```

I've opened the Windows' Command Prompt and type:

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile.am
```

The output:

```
mingw32-make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

I don't know why this error shows up.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about the tools available.

A `Makefile.am` is not a makefile.  It's an automake file.  Automake is a tool that will take in a description of a makefile (the `Makefile.am` file) and a set of configuration options (typically, but not necessarily, generated by the auto-configuration tool `autoconf`), and generate a makefile named `Makefile`.

Then you can run `make` with that `Makefile` in order to build your system.

These tools (autoconf and automake) are very important to portable software because so many of the UNIX-like systems have slight differences.  These tools help you abstract away all those differences and even support new systems which you've never used before.

On Windows this is not so important, since most Windows systems are pretty similar and backward-compatible.  So I doubt most people who are targeting Windows-only environments bother with autoconf and automake.

Comment: THx for your answer, i've got that the makefile.am is not the makefile
so now how can i build that project ?

Comment: The short answer is, you can't build this on Windows.  It's created for a UNIX environment.  If you want to build it on Windows you'll first have to port it to Windows (I'm assuming it's not already ported, and that the README file etc. that comes with the source doesn't tell you how to build it on Windows).  Porting a program to Windows is far beyond the scope of a site like StackOverflow.